# Why process killed with nohup

Tags: background-process, nohup, uwsgi

I want to run a process in background without killing it on shell exit, according to Nohup concept the following command should work until I kill it manually:

```
nohup uwsgi --http :8008  --module crawled_data_center.wsgi > /dev/null &
```

I'm logged in with root user to shell, but after exit the shell, the process got terminated. It seems weird because I've used `nohup` several times in several projects and works correctly but in this case I've sucked, what is the problem and how can I run it in background without killing it on shell exit?

**Update:**

I handled it with:

```
$ nohup uwsgi --http :8008  --module crawled_data_center.wsgi > /dev/null &
$ disown -l
$ disown -h JOBID
```

But my question is about how could it be possible `SIGHUP` could kill `nohup` and `&` ?

Here is the content of `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
Controllers=blkio cpu cpuacct cpuset devices freezer hugetlb memory perf_event net_cls net_prio
ResetControllers=
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
```

Comment: @Fox Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to run this as a service?

Comment: @ErikF do you better plan? I want my django project stay running when I leave the shell. I combine uwsgi with nginx and django.

Comment: @Fox it's wired, I resolve this issue by using disown but It's not normal.

Comment: @Fox it seems as a good idea, but I've remembered It'd worked before.

Comment: @Yusef Using disown does not help me.

Comment: @mathsyouth it worked for me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As far as I know, there are two situations that can cause a process to be killed after being protected by `nohup`, and each situation has a different workaround.

One possibility, which does not appear to be the case here, is that the system uses systemd where `logind.conf` is configured with `KillUserProcesses=yes`.  In this case, closing the terminal will not cause problems, but logging out of the system will. The workaround in this case is to use

```
$ systemd-run --scope --user [command]
```

This basically just tells systemd that it should not kill the process.

The other possibility is that the spawned process implements its own handler for `SIGHUP` which overrides the protection of `nohup`. In this case, problems will occur as soon as the shell is closed, even if you remain logged in. You can check for this with:

```
$ nohup [command] &
$ grep Sig /proc/$!/status
```

You should see a line

```
SigIgn: 0000000000000001
```

(or some other string of hexadecimal digits). `SIGHUP` is signal number `1`, so if this big-endian hexadecimal number has its first (least-significant) bit set (that is, the final digit is one of 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, B, D, or F), then `SIGHUP` is ignored. Otherwise, the program has installed its own handler overriding the protection of `nohup`.

In this case, the solution is to use `disown`:

```
nohup [command] & disown
```

This removes the process from the shell's job list, preventing `SIGHUP` from being sent in the first place.

Comment: I met the same problem. But your solution to use `disown` doesn't work for me. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If the program you are using still dies on shell-exit with `disown`, it is a different problem. You could try running in `screen` (or similar) in detached mode