# NOHUP stopped working

Tags: process, nohup, disown

I've been using nohup for years on my server without any issue. Suddenly today it stopped working and the process ends as soon as I exit SSH. I have multiple accounts on this server and the problem is happening with one account but not the other. Is there a server setting anywhere that would affect this? I've also tried DISOWN but has the same issue. How can I get to the bottom of figuring out why this is happening?

I'm running it like:

nohup dotnet /home/MyProgram.dll/MyProgram.dll >/dev/null 2>&1 &

Comment: Check without the `nohup`, the redirection, the backgrounding. Does it even work?

Comment: Yes. It runs fine with or without nohup, but the process dies when I logout of SSH.

Comment: What operating system are you using? On systems that make use of systemd some options in `logind.conf` (e.g. `KillUserProcesses`) may be used to have users' processes killed when they log out.

Comment: Related: [Why process killed with nohup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420594/why-process-killed-with-nohup)

Comment: In case your shell is Bash, could it have anything to do with the `huponexit` option?